# Populate drop down list from array items Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of information as such:

```
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1", "February,104967,274354,1", "March,202394,343509,1", "April,187532,94652,1", "May,138745,206456,1", "June,234857,143657,1", "July,193453,203433,1", "August,96343,45064,1", "September,371298,505635,1", "October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1", "December,98642,173125,1"];
```

I am trying to create 2 drop down lists that are populated with the items in the first line of the array:

```
<!DOCTYPE html!>

<html>
<body>

  <div id="myModalTemplate" class="modal">
   <p>X-Axis Data</p>
    <p><select name="xaxis"></select></p>
    <p>Y-Axis Data</p>
    <p><select name="yaxis"></select></p>
    <p>Create A Title for Your Chart</p>
  <p><button>Generate Chart</button</p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>html>
```

Instead of writing an option for each item, the item can be different and instead I need a way to read the first line in the array then pull out the items and display them within both of the drop down lists

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve or what you've tried so far.  Can you show your attempt and the output you expect to create?

Comment: Are you, for instance, expecting two dropdowns, each of which lists (in this case) "Month", "Expenditure", "Income", and "Year"?  Or is there something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something that would work.  It would be more complex to remove the X-axis selected item from the Y-axis list and/or vice-versa.  But it could be done.

```js
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1", "February,104967,274354,1", "March,202394,343509,1", "April,187532,94652,1", "May,138745,206456,1", "June,234857,143657,1", "July,193453,203433,1", "August,96343,45064,1", "September,371298,505635,1", "October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1", "December,98642,173125,1"];

const select1 = document.querySelector('select[name=xaxis]');
const select2 = document.querySelector('select[name=yaxis]');

myArray[0].split(',').forEach(item => {
    select1.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item;
    select2.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item;
});
```

```html
<div id="myModalTemplate" class="modal">
 <p>X-Axis Data</p>
  <p><select name="xaxis"></select></p>
  <p>Y-Axis Data</p>
  <p><select name="yaxis"></select></p>
  <p>Create A Title for Your Chart</p>
<p><button>Generate Chart</button></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the array, something like this:

```js
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1", "February,104967,274354,1", "March,202394,343509,1", "April,187532,94652,1", "May,138745,206456,1", "June,234857,143657,1", "July,193453,203433,1", "August,96343,45064,1", "September,371298,505635,1", "October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1", "December,98642,173125,1"];

const select = document.querySelector('select[name=xaxis]');
myArray.forEach(item => {
  select.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item.split(',')[0];
});
```

```html
<div id="myModalTemplate" class="modal">
 <p>X-Axis Data</p>
  <p><select name="xaxis"></select></p>
  <p>Y-Axis Data</p>
  <p><select name="yaxis"></select></p>
  <p>Create A Title for Your Chart</p>
<p><button>Generate Chart</button</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I was thinking but instead, the options would be "Month", "Expenditure", "income", "Year" only. There would be 4 options to choose from

Comment: You asked for the way to do it - this is the general way to do it. Select the `select` element, and `forEach` over the array. If you want to do the same thing for multiple `selects`, it's just a matter of copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

This splits the options string and adds the axis option to the appropriate select box

```js
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1", "February,104967,274354,1", "March,202394,343509,1", "April,187532,94652,1", "May,138745,206456,1", "June,234857,143657,1", "July,193453,203433,1", "August,96343,45064,1", "September,371298,505635,1", "October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1", "December,98642,173125,1"];
window.onload = function(){
  for(var i = 1; i<myArray.length; i++){
    var info = myArray[i];
    var infoArr = info.split(',');
    
    var xaxis = document.querySelector('[name=xaxis]');
    var xoption = document.createElement('option');
    xoption.setAttribute("name", infoArr[1]);
    xoption.text = info;

    xaxis.appendChild(xoption);
    
    var yaxis = document.querySelector('[name=yaxis]');
    var yoption = document.createElement('option');
    yoption.setAttribute("name", infoArr[2]);
    yoption.text = info;
    yaxis.appendChild(yoption);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myModalTemplate" class="modal">
   <p>X-Axis Data</p>
    <p><select name="xaxis"></select></p>
    <p>Y-Axis Data</p>
    <p><select name="yaxis"></select></p>
    <p>Create A Title for Your Chart</p>
  <p><button>Generate Chart</button</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close but I only want the options "Month, Income, Expenditure, year" as the 4 options available

Comment: @JoshGoldsmith: You want those for both X- and Y- axes?

Comment: @Josh Sorry I'm not quiete understanding. Do you mean you want the four options in the options text eg. January,187458,297664,1?

Comment: Yes, the idea is the user chooses which set should be the x and which set should be the y

Comment: I'm still not 100%, but I've updated the code so the option text shows the  four values. Is the X axis the Expenditure?

Comment: The only selectable options within the drop down are to be: Month, Expenditure, Income, Year. Not the values it represents, but just the word. The idea is that the user would create a bar chart, this part allows the user to select the values of the X axis to be one variable and the Y axis to be another one, so "Month" for X and "Income" for Y etc.